# how to search items in a string in a specific order

Tags: python

I was working on some problems and recently I got stuck on one. I have a string like `'hoouseeqwehouusseee'`. I have to count how many characters are between the first word `'house'` and the other word `'house'`. For the above example the extra letters would be: `'e'`, `'q'`, `'w'`, `'e'` so the answer is `4`. I tried to convert the string into a list but from here I don't know how to proceed.

```
word = list(word)
x = []
for item in word:
    if item not in x:
        x.append(item)
print(x)
```

Comment: `'house'` does not appear in your string. you have `'hoousee'`

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus I know that, but doesn't help solving the problem.

Comment: @bphi duplicate letters are allowed inside the word

Comment: _I know that, but doesn't help solving the problem._ You're question is not helping us answer you neither. You really need to clarify your problem.

Comment: Are duplicate letters also allowed at the start or end of the word "house"?

Comment: (a) you need to be much more clear on your requirements as the word `house` never appears. Typo? If not then you need to explain. (b) why (exactly why) do you want to create a list and what do you expect this final list to look like?

Comment: @Dan you are right. So, if the sequence of letters 'house' happened, then, I have to count all characters until the new 'house' sequence of letters appears. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: If "hoousee" and "houusseee" both count as "house" with permitted duplicate letters, then there are only 3 letters between them: "qwe".

Comment: @Dante no that's not clearer, that's just repeating yourself

Comment: @PM2Ring, no because the 'house' sequence ended after the first 'e'

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a solution hope it really do what you really meant on your question.

code :-

```
word = 'hoouseeqwehouusseee'
def count_char(string):
    new_string1 = word.replace('hoouse','')
    new_string2 = new_string1.replace('houusseee','')
    return len(new_string2)

print(count_char(word))
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As your requirements aren't clear this probably won't solve your exact problem, but it should give you a start. This will return the number of letters between the first and second instance of a string matching `h+o+u+s+e` regex.

```
import re

s = 'hoouseeqwehouusseee'

def length_of_first_gap(test_string, word):
    pattern = '+'.join(list(word))
    return len(re.split(pattern, test_string)[1])

>>> length_of_first_gap(s, 'house')
>>> 4
```

Comment: If I use print(length_of_first_gap('footbaallllleqeqwfoootbaaall', 'football')) it will show only 5 instead of 8

Comment: it should count extra letters at end or beggining of the given word. here it should have counted 'llleqeqw'

Comment: The two trailing `l`s make it ambiguous. What should `length_of_first_gap('aaaaaaa', 'aa)` return?

Comment: just 0, since no other letters between the 'aa'

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use regular expressions.

1. First we find all matches in our string.
2. Than we calculate difference between end of one and start of next match.

Here is a code:

```
import re
string = 'hoouseeqwehouusseee'
word = 'house'

pattern = '+'.join(word)
list_of_word_indices = [(match.start(0), match.end(0)) for match in re.finditer(pattern, string)]
list_of_gap_lengthes = [list_of_word_indices[i+1][0] - list_of_word_indices[i][1]
                        for i in range(len(list_of_word_indices)-1)] 

print(list_of_gap_lengthes)
```

You'll have list of gaps in return. In your example that's **'[4]'**

Hope that helps.

Comment: This gives you a list of lengths of gaps.  If you have 3 instances of 'house', code will return list of 2 distances.

Comment: for 'hoouseeewerhouusseaaahouse' you'll have [5, 3],
for ''hoouseeewerhouusse' you'll have [5]

Answer (score -3):

collections.Counter will help you: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```
import collections
...
word = ...
counter = collections.Counter(word)
```

Comment: This is closer to a comment than an answer.